Laptop with EOS v8.0 not booting today
So,
As a supporter, I have access to v8.0, which I installed on my Dell XPS 13 9333 laptop that I've had for literally a decade.
All was well. Yesterday I wasn't paying attention and the battery got dangerously low before I shut the lid.
In previous versions of EOS (v7.1), typically it would require a restart after charging after this scenario.
Today proceeded very much the same way, only after seeing the EOS logo and the spinner, the screen goes dark never to return.
If I touch the power button I get the logo and spinner again for a moment and then the machine turns off.
I can boot in recovery mode via the esc key during boot. This seems to be merely a recovery tool.
I can also get to the command line via CTRL-ALT-F1 after it goes to a blank screen. Logged in as the normal user. Both internal and NAS shares mounted. Connected to the network. Everything functional except Wayland. I can even run my favorite command line tool, Midnight Commander.
Doing loginctl results in:
SESSION  UID USER  SEAT  TTY  STATE  IDLE SINCE
      2 1000 chris seat0 tty1 active no   -

1 sessions listed.

Doing loginctl session-status 2 results in:
2 - chris (1000)
  Since: Fri 2024-10-11 09:56:32 EDT; 9min ago
  State: active
 Leader: 1054 (login)
   Seat: seat0; vc1
    TTY: tty1
 Remote: no
Service: login
   Type: tty
  Class: user
   Idle: no
   Unit: session-2.scope
         ├─1054 /bin/login -p --
         ├─1644 -bash
         └─2451 loginctl session-status 2

Oct 11 09:58:55 XPS13 gnome-session-binary[2112]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit  not found.
Oct 11 09:58:56 XPS13 gnome-session[2112]: gnome-session-binary[2112]: WARNING: Could not get session id for session. Check that logind is properly installed and pam_systemd is getting used at login.
Oct 11 09:58:56 XPS13 gnome-session-binary[2112]: WARNING: Could not get session id for session. Check that logind is properly installed and pam_systemd is getting used at login.
Oct 11 09:58:56 XPS13 gnome-session-binary[2112]: Entering running state
Oct 11 10:00:19 XPS13 gnome-session[2394]: gnome-session-binary[2394]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit  not found.
Oct 11 10:00:19 XPS13 gnome-session-binary[2394]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit  not found.
Oct 11 10:00:19 XPS13 gnome-session[2394]: gnome-session-binary[2394]: WARNING: Could not get session id for session. Check that logind is properly installed and pam_systemd is getting used at login.
Oct 11 10:00:19 XPS13 gnome-session-binary[2394]: WARNING: Could not get session id for session. Check that logind is properly installed and pam_systemd is getting used at login.
Oct 11 10:00:19 XPS13 gnome-session-binary[2394]: Entering running state
Oct 11 10:00:19 XPS13 gnome-session-f[2403]: Cannot open display:
gnome-session-tty@gnome.targetgnome-session-tty@gnome-wayland.targetgnome-session-tty@gnome-wayland.target

Any idea how do I repair this?
Thanks
